# python regex strips out backslash

Tags: python, regex

With this code I get:

```
newContent='asdf asdf \nOUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = working\topOnly'
```

I'd expect it to be:

```
newContent='asdf asdf \nOUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = working\\topOnly'
```

The reg ex is stripping out a `"""\"""` between  `"""working"""` and `"""topOnly"""`.  If I do something like `"""valStr = 'working\\ytopOnly'"""` then it works as expected.

What do I need to change in my code so that it was as expected?

```
import re

valStr = 'working\\topOnly'
cmdFileContent = 'asdf asdf \nOUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = asdf'
name = 'OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'

varRegEx = r"""
    (\n          #match new line
    %s            #var
    \s*           #skip white spaces
    =
    \s?)          #skip white spaces
    (.*)          #match and store rest of line
    """%name

newContent  = re.compile(varRegEx, re.VERBOSE).sub(r'\1%s'%valStr, cmdFileContent)
```

Comment: the real and expected output is same on question, please edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for re.sub says:

> repl can be either a string or a callable; if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.

Since it's doing its own layer of processing escapes, you will need *another* layer of escapes:

```
newContent = re.compile(varRegEx, re.VERBOSE).sub(r'\1%s'%valStr.replace('\\', '\\\\'), cmdFileContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Has nothing to do with reg-exp at all.  Try this:

```
 valStr = 'working\\topOnly'
 print valStr
```

You think `print` is "stripping out" one of your back-slashes too?  Maybe it's a conspiracy!

It's just the Python parser itself.  Like almost every language parser, it treats backslash as an escape, so `g\\t` means g-backslash-t, whereas `g\t` means 'g-tab'.  Try

```
 valStr = 'working\\\\topOnly'
```

Comment: My IDE shows the repr version of strings. Mu Mind solution works.  Thank you for your help